# Hooking SSDT. Other driver uses my function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel, driver

How can I get the driver name or driver path inside its context? I mean when not my driver uses syscall and i hook it, i need to get this driver's name. For user processes there is no problem:

```
PUNICODE_STRING myname;
SeLocateProcessImageName(PsGetCurrentProcess(), &myname);
```

But if alien driver uses hooked syscall, its PID is 4. And I cannot get name like above...
Here it is full hook's code:

```
    NTSTATUS
HookNtTerminateProcess(
    HANDLE hProcess,
    NTSTATUS ExitStatus
    )
{
    NTSTATUS statuscod;
    if (hProcess == NULL || hProcess == (HANDLE)-1 || hProcess<2) {
        return fnNtTerminateProcess(hProcess, ExitStatus);
    }
    if (PsGetCurrentProcessId() == 4)
    {
        ???????????????????????????
    }
    PUNICODE_STRING name;
    getPathByProcessHandle(hProcess, &name);
    PUNICODE_STRING myname;
    SeLocateProcessImageName(PsGetCurrentProcess(), &myname);

    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "\n-------------------------------------------\n");
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "KILL TO PROCESS WITH HANDLE %d\n", hProcess);
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "WHO: %S\n", myname->Buffer);
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "TARGET: %S\n", name->Buffer);
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "PID is %d\n", PsGetCurrentProcessId());

    NTSTATUS status;
    if (wcsstr(name->Buffer, L"Windows\\protecteddir\\myapp.exe") == NULL) {
        return fnNtTerminateProcess(hProcess, ExitStatus);
    }
    sendEvent(0, PsGetCurrentProcessId());
    return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```

Comment: Hooking the SSDT?  Sounds like a [rootkit](https://www.adlice.com/kernelmode-rootkits-part-1-ssdt-hooks/).

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR it's not 4 on every version of NT, older versions used different numbers, as high as 8 IIRC.

Comment: If you want to prevent process attacks, there's kernel-mode callbacks officially supported by Microsoft: ObRegisterCallbacks, PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine/Ex and PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine/Ex. You could make a watch-dog with PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine/Ex/Ex2 as well. Use those instead if you want whatever you're making to not suck. Because controlling NtTerminateProcess via SSDT hooking sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers utilize the system process which generally has the process Id of 0x04. Drivers are mapped into the memory as named sections and are then executed by a thread. They are not separate processes as can be seen when you cannot uniquely identify their name through process information as it all is just part of the system process.

These are some possibilities for identifying which driver the caller is related to that I know of. For all cases if the process Id is the system process (0x04) or the previous [KPROCESSOR_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-exgetpreviousmode) is not user-mode:

1) Trace the call stack for the current thread trapped in your system service routine hook and see the address range of the caller and determine which memory section the address in range belongs to. The object attributes for the section will specify the name such as "driver.sys". This will be the name of the base driver the call originated from

2) Use [ZwQueryInformationThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt629133(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress as an argument for ThreadInformationClass, this will tell you where the thread started executing, then determine which named memory section the base execution address is in. This will be stored in the memory section's [OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_object_attributes). This will also resolve a name for which base driver the call originated from.

3) If this is to make sure that only your thread normally executes the system service routine hook, then change an unused/reserved field in your thread's ETHREAD/KTHREAD structure to uniquely identify it and except all other thread's.

These are some solutions, but uniquely targeting and identify threads in the system process should work.